# Can't mock a module method when importing by name

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I don't understand why I can't do this operation when trying to mock `time.sleep()` -- the `sleep()` method will still delay the given time:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from time import sleep

class TestTime(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('time.sleep', return_value=None)
    def test_time(self, mock_time):
        sleep(10) # still delays 10s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This works properly:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import time

class TestTime(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('time.sleep', return_value=None)
    def test_time(self, mock_time):
        time.sleep(10) # instant

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This results in an error `TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'sleep'`:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from time import sleep

class TestTime(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('sleep', return_value=None) # error
    def test_time(self, mock_time):
        sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is there a proper way to mock `sleep()` without needing to change all the modules I'm trying to test to use `time.sleep()`?

My setup:

- Python version: 3.8.12
- OS: Windows 10 21H1 (19043.1766)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason importing `sleep` by name doesn't allow `patch` to work in the examples is that `patch` is looking for attribute names on an object in order to patch it.  When importing by name, the object isn't provided and thus why there is a TypeError.  The `sleep` method is now in the namespace of the module importing it, so you can use that to properly patch `sleep`.

To import `sleep` by name and properly patch it, the following will work:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from time import sleep

class TestTime(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('__main__.sleep', return_value=None)
    def test_time(self, mock_time):
        sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As a caveat, if you have a module named `my_module` that uses `from time import sleep` and a separate file for tests, you can do the following within the test file to patch `sleep` within `my_module`:

`@patch('my_module.sleep', return_value=None)`